# Using namespase USE in a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, namespace

I'm writing several joomla modules and I'd like to put common functions in the libraries folder.  However I want to use them from a joomla Ajax call in my module.  I'm preparing to upgrade from 3.x to 4.x

I have the Ajax working fine.  The part I can't get to work is using the USE php.

I have:

libraries/practicemanagement/patientForm.php

and in my module i have in the entry php file

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

require_once 'libraries/practicemanagement/patientForm.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';


$siteButtons  = modPatientChargeCheckingHelper::getSiteButtons();
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_patient_charge_checking', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

the patietForm.php contains two functions:

```
<?php
trait patientForm
{
    /**
     * The Main Active Language
     *
     * @var      string
     *
     * @since  3.0.9
     */
    public static function getPxAddress($addressId){...}

    public static function getSiteButtons($siteToUse =""){...}
}
```

The helper class has:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class  modPatientChargeCheckingHelper

{

    use patientForm;

    public static function getAjax(){}

}
```

When the file loads it runs the getSiteButtons() function however I think this is running just because it is included via the require_once statement.  When I try to use the Helper Ajax function  it just gives  a  500 error.  I've searched the server log and there doesn't seem to be an issue.  I've never used USE before so I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong.  I just need a pointer to help me figure out what.

thanks

php 7.4.33
Joomla! 3.10.11 Stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry file is not used when calling AJAX. You have to move the loading of `patientForm.php` into the helper file, before the class declaration:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once 'libraries/practicemanagement/patientForm.php';

class modPatientChargeCheckingHelper
{
    use patientForm;

    public static function getAjax(){}

}
```

Comment: Worked!!  I'm very happy thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

More or less a similar approach as what @Sharky has provided however my example is from a working Component, not a Module, so I am not sure if that is going to be an issue for you. It replaces the require_once with a Use statement for the library.

```
namespace Irata\Component\Mycomponent\Administrator\View\Barney;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use ...
use Irata\Component\MyComponent\Administrator\Library\FredsTrait;

class HtmlView extends BaseHtmlView
{
    use FredsTrait;
....
}
```

I create a Component specific Library in my extensions therefore if your Modules are part of a package relating to a single component you might find this is an alternative to using the site wide library aproach.